# Dropdown when press a button

Tags: javascript, button

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Hi! I want to do something like this. When I press a button, in my image the button is '+', a pop up appears below

I've been looking for but have not found anything..

Comment: What did you try for that???

Comment: You could use JQuery Accordion to do that: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: It's not a real dropdown, It uses Javascript or Jquery to show/hide/toggle the fields:  jquery show() hide() toggle() example. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: Thanks Teuta, but I'm working on javascript and that is HTML

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea

HTML Code:

```
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

You can do it using jQuery functions to slide up/down but if you don't need animation effect it's probably too much for what you need.